# Ruby script can't find gem when running under another user

Tags: ruby, nagios, icinga

I have written a icinga2(nagios) check in ruby.  It uses the splunk-sdk-ruby gem and works perfectly when I run it either as my user or as root.  But when I add it in to icinga2 to run, I get a gem load error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby- .2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- splunk-sdk-ruby (LoadError)
```

I already require rubygems above the gem I need in my script.
It looks like icinga2 is running under the icinga user, but I can't do a su - to that user to install the gem cause it says: This account is currently not available.

What am I missing here to make the gem available to all users?

Comment: Did you do `sudo gem install splunk-sdk-ruby yor_gem_name_here`?

Comment: I was running as the root user when I installed it

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be `root` permissions for the different users in your system.